# how to get Image coordinate (with respect to original image) if the window gets resize in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

I am working on a project where Image is getting display into a grid panel. and I need to show different tooltip on different areas of image.  i can hard code the image coordinates but the issue is when I resize the window, the hard code part will not work.

kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for you:

```
<Grid>
    <Image />
    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="2">
        <UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            </Style>
        </UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Border ToolTip="0,0"/>
        <Border ToolTip="0,1"/>
        <Border ToolTip="1,0"/>
        <Border ToolTip="1,1"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

The borders are for demonstration only. Use more columns and rows for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your help....actually this didn't solve my problem. Let me explain my issue with the help of example.

Comment: 1. the initial/original coordinate of the image with total height and width.
2. x-y coordinates, height and width of every cabin/area according to the original image.

things works until image or window get resize. 
I am streching image to fill the panel.

Comment: Thanks for your help....actually this didn't solve my problem. Let me explain my issue with the help of example. 
suppose, we have a building blueprint as an image per floor and that blue print shows different cabins of different person/team. the symbol blue print use, could be small rectangle for small cabin, large rectangle for large area. also the shapes are not limited to rectangle. they could be star, polygon or any other shape.
the only thing available at design time is